# Converting a switch/base form validator to something that supports more than a single case

Tags: javascript, switch-statement, object-literal

I'm attempting to change a form input validator **from handling errors 1 by 1**, to **handle errors all at once**. Since there are a lot of moving parts, I'll try and isolate the key area of the component.

https://codepen.io/jodriscoll/pen/pXyMqa?editors=0010

```
129: while ( error < rules.length ) {
130:     if ( !validations[rules[error]](vin_input.value) ) {
```

When there are rules (input requirements) defined, extract the input's `value`, then pass that `value` to `validations`'s inner functions. If one of those functions within returns `false`, validation stops and the `switch` (error output) handles which error needs to be addressed (based on priority/order).

```
41: const validations = {
43:     // goal is to return true, then try the next validation requirement (order matters)
44:     required: function(value) {
45:         return value !== '';
46:     },
47:     special: function(value) {
48:         return value.match(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/g) == null;
49:     },
50:     restricted: function(value) {
51:         return value.match(/[IiOoQq]/g) == null;
52:     },
53:     quantity: function(value) {
54:         return value.length > 16;
55:     },
56: };
```

**The problem:** 
Due to this `switch` statement, it will stop handling future/additional errors, if the rule return value qualifies for a case condition. My goal is to allow the user to incur multiple errors (for this case, searching for "A*IQ&"), then when they submit the form, they'll receive alerts for each of the errors detected, not the highest priority.

```
179: switch( rules[error] ) {
189:     case 'required':
```

I'm considering handling the error within an Object Literal, but would rather receive advice and (possibly) examples of different opinions.

**UPDATE #1:**
I was able to work around this as an FYI (https://codepen.io/jodriscoll/pen/XLKKwa?editors=0010), but I'm not happy with the "bloat" and wanted to use a better approach.

Comment: I would use an object literal to hold the errors, or even an array of objects if there's a need for multiple errors of a specific type (ie: 2 special errors).

Answer (score 0):

I would consider using an object to track errors that maybe looks something like this. This supports multiple errors of the same type.

```
let validations = {
  isValid: false,
  errors: [
    {
      type: 'required',
      message: 'You must provide a phone number.'
    },
    {
      type: 'quantity',
      message: 'The quantity selected must be between x and y.'
    }
  ]
}
```

Then you can refactor the switch statement to something more like this:

```
validations.errors.forEach((error) => {
  switch(error.type){
    case 'required':
      // Do something.
      break;
    case 'quantity':
      // Do something else
      // etc...
  }
})
```

Comment: Thanks! I will explore utilizing this in a codepen and report back my findings.